# iOS Navbar Appearing Faded

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

The navbar color appears faded at the top. I'm using a UINavigationController, and the navbar is showing up a lot lighter than it should. Any ideas on how to fix it? Here is my code:

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = false
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.459, green: 0.102, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict as? Dictionary
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your `.plist` file. Then, set style Black and you problem should be fixed.

[image: plist]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Do the following change
2.You are setting background color so it is faded but we have to set bartint color

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

This will set the bartint color to red, you can set any you want